# Use sed to add text from one file to match pattern of another file

Tags: sed

I'm using sed and I need to add text from file 2 to end of every line in file 1.

I tried using something like `sed 's/.*/name & /' input.txt > output.txt`, but it won't work.

`file1` contains:

```
name,text1,
name,text2,
name,text3,
```

`file2` contains:

```
animals.com
cars.com
planes.com
```

final output:

```
name,text1,animals.com
name,text2,cars.com
name,text3,planes.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
paste -d ' ' file1 file2 | sed "s/ //"
```

Answer (score 0):

by bash shell;

```
i=1;while read l ;do sed -En "$i{s/.*/$l&/p;q}" file2 ;let i++; done<file1
```

if file1 has space, first preset IFS=''

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '=' file2 |
sed 'N;s/\n\(.*\)/s#$#\1#/' |
sed -f - file1
```

Precede each line of file2 with its line number.

Convert each line of file2 into a substitution, appending the contents of its line to the same line number of the intended file.

Run a third invocation of sed to apply the manufactured sed script against file1.

Alternative:

```
parallel echo {1}{2} :::: file1 ::::+ file2
```